# What does "binary string" means in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm reading [the doc of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex). Where I found the `UNHEX` function is described as:

> For a string argument str, UNHEX(str) interprets each pair of characters in the argument as a hexadecimal number and converts it to the byte represented by the number. **The return value is a binary string.**

```
mysql> SELECT UNHEX('4D7953514C');
        -> 'MySQL'
mysql> SELECT X'4D7953514C';
        -> 'MySQL'
mysql> SELECT UNHEX(HEX('string'));
        -> 'string'
mysql> SELECT HEX(UNHEX('1267'));
        -> '1267'
```

What is a "binary string"? Is it a  general term or a term specifically used in MySQL?

I thought that if it is a "binary" data, then it shouldn't be called as a "string"(array of chars). So I'm wondering what is "binary string"?? does it means "array of bytes"?

I assume that eventually every datatype will be converted into binary data. And so does the "String Types" in MySQL. What makes the difference from a "string" and a "binary string" is that the "character string" has some information about what encoding schema and collation to be used when MySQL covert it from binary to a character string.

So what I don't quite understand is that why UNHEX('4D7953514C') returns a "character string" `'MySQL'` but not a "binary string" represented by a sequence of 0s and 1s(0100 1101 0111 1001 0101 0011 0101 0001 0100 1100).

Comment: in good old C it's this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "binary string" in general means a sequence of 0s and 1s. In the case of the MySQL function unhex, it takes a string of hexadecimal values and converts it into a binary number, which will be represented as a string. Nothing fancy here. The result will be a string, which is the result of converting from hexadecimal number to binary number. A hexadecimal number is of four digits when converting into binary. The resulting sequence of 0s and 1s will be the binary representation of the resulting string.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question a little bit. Just to make sure if I understood correctly. By "which will be represented as a string", do you mean an "array of chars" but not an "array of 0s and 1s"? If it is, what encoding schema to be used when MySQL convert a binary sequence to "array of chars"? Why MySQL want to convert the binary sequence to "array of chars"? Why not just literal binary data…?

Comment: @yaquawa The input is a string of hexadecimal digits and the output is a string of bytes, or a string of 0s and 1s, if you will. It will be represented as a string, but it is essentially a binary number. You can use the encoding you prefer to vary the output. Here the difference between binary string and string is semantic. While a string in most cases is a result of user input, a text, in this case, the binary string is the result of a number base conversion. Strings, in most cases are texts, here they are numbers. The way how we look at them makes the difference.

Answer (score 3):

As mysql manual on [binary and varbinary data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) says, binary strings

> contain byte strings rather than character strings. This means they have the binary character set and collation, and comparison and sorting are based on the numeric values of the bytes in the values.

Essentialy, they are arrays of bytes.

Comment: What does this mean though ? I have seen so many answers where the same quote, i created a table and added some characters like A,B,C with the binary type, but they did not store them as binary ?